# Angular Spring Boot Packaging Issue

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot

I have the current project structure for a spring boot angular project

```
+--app-ui
|--+--src
|--+--dist
|--app-backend
|--+--src
|--+--+--main
|--+--+--+--resources
|--+--+--+--+--static
|--+--+--+--java
```

app-ui contains the angular 6 code app backend contains the spring boot code. Now everytime I build app-ui i want the dist folder contents in app-ui to be copied to app-backend/src/main/resources/static

In order to do that I have added these lines in the angular build

```
"predeploy": "rimraf ../app-backend/src/main/resources/static/ && mkdirp ../app-backend/src/main/resources/static",

"deploy": "copyfiles -f dist/** ../app-backend/src/main/resources/static/
```

This creates the static folder inside Spring boot project but it doesn't copy the files and folders inside dist folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using AngularCLI (with an angular.json file), simply change the `outputPath` property to specify your desired static directory.

```
"outputPath": "../app-backend/src/main/resources/static"
```

Comment: Thanks. This is much simpler than configuring in springboot pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way for integrating my angular app with spring-boot so the static code is atleast in spring boot app path. But I still couldn't see user interface when my spring app is running on port 8080.
Not sure if I'm missing something but majority of my frontend code that is; ng components .ts, .html and .css files are in frontend/src dir, which I didn't move anywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your Controller returning the index.html?

Comment: @Swastik I don't think that I need a controller to return index.html, not sure though. Because index.html is now already in the path of spring-boot app(/resources/static dir) so didn't make any controller especially to serve this.

Comment: you need to have a index controller that returns the index.html.

Comment: The routing will be handled by angular from there

Comment: @Swastik thanks for pointing out. I created a controller , but cannot see UI except I do see a string printed "index.html"which  I am returning in controller. I do see angular icon on chrome tab which means it is able to point correctly but index.html pretty much has nothing. body tag mentions root angular component.  Here is exact problem if you could help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52079379/how-to-integrate-angular-with-spring-boot-to-see-angular-web-interface-on-spring