# How to integrate angular with spring boot to see angular web interface on spring boot port?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, angular-cli, angular4-router

I have backend spring boot app and front-end developed using angular4. Since these 2 operate on different ports(8080,4200) when deploying, it isn't showing any UI. In local, starting angular server using below works absolutely fine on localhost:4200 and shows web interface:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

where proxy.conf.json has contents:

```
{
  "*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

But not when trying to integrate with springboot app(localhost:8080). Probably, it requires ng business logic(node/npm install etc.) to be baked before deployment.

So I used `ng build` which copied generated files to a output dir - src/main/resources/static and now it's in spring-boot app path. Starting tomcat still shows no UI on localhost:8080. I do see Angular symbol/icon on chrome tab but nothing shown on html page.

I also added a controller method to return index.html so that it can serve static files in path.

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "forward:/index.html";
}
```

But doing this just displays "forward:/index.html" string instead of html content on webpage.
Do I need to change something in this index.html so that it can route to  ng components that I have created? 
Don't know if it matters to change selector in index.html. Since my main component is not app component(which is by default the root component) rather a login component so in index.html I changed `<app-root></app-root>` to login component's selector `<app-login></app-login>`; still nothing shows up in UI.

Seems like spring-boot isn't able to understand angular stuff and how to route to main ng components.

Below is index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Hello App</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Project structure:

```
-src
 -main
  -java
    - backend
      - AppController
      - AppService
      - Main.java
    - frontend
      - src
        - index.html
        - app
          -login
           - login.component.html
           - login.component.css
           - login.component.ts
          etc..
  - resources
    - static
      - index.html
      - application.properties
      - ...
```

How can I have the frontend work with backend server when deployment? Do I need to add any argument or configuration in application.properties for the app to serve static content from /resources on startup ? Do I add any resourceLocationHandler for serving it?

Any help , very much appreciated!

Comment: hi. why do you have Angular sources under /src/main/java/frontend ?  it would be much cleaner, if you have possibility to change that, to have a main project and two sub-projects: one for backend (with java project type) , one for fronend (standard  Angular app).

Comment: And if you use gradle for building your project, you can check this project which integrates properly Angular 5 with Spring boot : https://github.com/dmitrij-drandarov/Spring-5-Angular-4-Gradle-Example :

Comment: I created ng components in frontend /src dir. But like you said; I have maintained the main project having 2 dir , one for backend (src/main/java/backendapp) and the other one for frontend (src/main/java/frontend) similar to the way this link you shared have the project structure.

Answer (score 1):

Please open the jar file with an archive utility and see if the static files are available in it. If they are available, you need to tell Spring that the URLs you are entering into the address bar are actually Angular routes:

```
@Controller
public class Routing {

    @RequestMapping({ "", "/login", "/products/**" })
    public String gui() {
        return "forward:/index.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this solution but this didn't work.

Comment: @SoC What do you observe? What do you see when you go to the url? Do your static files exist in the jar? Have you checked that by extracting the jar? Have you configured Spring to find the above controller by doing a component scan?

Comment: After making the controller and starting tomcat, I see the "index.html" string on webpage(localhost:8080). But after checking the contents of jar file using jar tvf project.jar, I don't see static files (index.html, main.js,style.js etc. basically any  contents of static folder in resource directory). Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Actually I was wrong, I can see the static contents in jar file(forgot to do gradle build ) but still i see just a string printed when browsed localhost:8080

Comment: @SoC why are you returning "index". Please write it the way it's shown in the above answer

Comment: I had already tried it that way, it prints forward:/index.html when browse to localhost:8080 . Not sure what I'm missing or where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I get past that issue of returning just string by replacing with @Controller on class level but still do not see any web ui content. I did notice 200 response code when hitting localhost:8080/ or localhost:8080/index.html or http://localhost:8080/runtime.js just no uI. I wonder if there is some issue in angular routing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using maven and the *frontend-maven-plugin*

First od all I agree about the fact to have the frontend separated by the backend

So i would create this project structure:

```
parentDirectory
- frontend
  - angular src files
  - pom.xml
- backend
  - spring boot based backend
  - pom.xml
- pom.xml
```

The parent `pom.xml` would be:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>test</groupId>
    <artifactId>apringangular</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>Spring angular</name>
    <modules>
        <module>backend</module>
        <module>frontend</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

The frontend pom would be:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>test</groupId>
        <artifactId>springangular</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>frontend</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>frontend_project_properties.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>dist</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <nodeVersion>v8.11.3</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>6.3.0</npmVersion>
                            <arguments>${http_proxy_config}</arguments>
                            <arguments>${https_proxy_config}</arguments>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                            <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>${http_proxy_config}</arguments>
                            <arguments>${https_proxy_config}</arguments>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                            <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Inside the file `frontend_project_properties.properties`I have my proxy configuration for node and npm. Something like this:

```
http_proxy_config=config set proxy http://USERNAME_PROXY:PASSWORD_PROXY@PROXY_HOST:PROXY_PORT
https_proxy_config=config set https-proxy http://USERNAME_PROXY:PASSWORD_PROXY@PROXY_HOST:PROXY_PORT
```

The backend pom is a classical spring boot backend. You must tell maven where the frontend is so maven is able in creating a unique webapplication. In the backend pom.xml you should add something like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>it.eng.tz.area.vasta.mev</groupId>
        <artifactId>appmgr</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>appmgrbackend</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Application manager backend</name>
    <description>
        Lato backend del sistema di gestione
    </description>
    <dependencies>
         <!-- Your dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>        
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>../frontend/dist</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

In this way you tell the `maven-war-plugin` that the HTML and static code is locate in the `dist` directory of frontend project
Note that during the development node.js serves resource on 4200 port while spring uses a different port. So you'll have a cross-site issue. By using spring security yuo can solve this issue bu configuring, in the backend side, spring security in this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(value= {AppMgrWebMvcConfig.class})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled=true)
public class AppMgrWebSecConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("oauthUsrDetailSvc")
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userPwdEnc")
    private PasswordEncoder pwdEncoder;
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web.httpFirewall(this.allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall());
    }
    @Bean
    public HttpFirewall allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall()
    {
        StrictHttpFirewall firewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true);
        firewall.setAllowSemicolon(true);
        return firewall;
    } 
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }
    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(pwdEncoder);
        return authenticationProvider;
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/**")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/rest/protected/**")
        .access("hasAnyRole('ADMIN','USER','SUPER_ADMIN')")
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/rest/public/**")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("http://localhost:8100/", true)
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .and()
        .logout()
        .permitAll()
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
        .cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedPage("/pages/accessDenied");
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200","http://localhost:8080"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-requested-with"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

This will let you to develope and compile all just only by using maven

Angelo

Comment: Thanks for sharing this Angelo but unfortunately can't use maven plugin for this app as its gradle based created service.